# Requirejs, basic information

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm learning Requirejs and I started with two simple `.html` pages: `index.html` and `second.html`.

On the `index.html` I worte:

`<script data-main="assets/js/app.min" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>`

The `app.min.js` file look like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/vendor',
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        jquery: 'jquery-1.10.1.min'
    }
});

requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

My `app/main.js` file has just a jQuery alert:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

    $(function() {

        alert('Hello World');

    });

});
```

It works fine!
Now I'm worried just about one thing... What about if I need to load the `app/main` globally for all my pages and then another file like `app/second` that run only on `second.html` page?

Probably I'm missing something about Requirejs... I don't thinks that I need to load everything on the `app.min.js` file like did for the `app/main`.

I understand that I can define modules on separate `js` files but then how can I manage different files for different pages without loading everything in just one file? Probably I'm wrong, I hope you can open the light in my brain for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that a page might need its own code *in addition* to what is in `app.min`. You could do something like this:

```
<script data-main="assets/js/app.min" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>
<script>
    // You can call the config function as many times as you need to add new configuration.
    requirejs.config({
        // Presumably, baseUrl does not need to be changed.
        // baseUrl: 'js/vendor',
        paths: {
            // additional paths you may need
        }
    });

    // This loads the code proper to this page.
    requirejs(["app/second"]);
</script>
```

If `app/second` depends on `app/main` make sure to have that dependency listed in `app/second`'s `define` call.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage. The example demonstrates how you can create page1.js and page2.js and in those files load the common stuff + page specific things. That's one of several ways to do it.

Another way to do which is what I often use is putting something like this in all your pages:

```
<script src="require.js"></script>  <!-- just require -->
<script src="app.min.js"></script>  <!-- your config and also loading the main module -->
```

and then on second.html, you would also add this

```
<script>require(["app/second"])</script>
```

You can use this setup for development, and for production you can replace the first 2 lines with just `<script src="optimized-bundle.js"></script>`. The `optimized-bundle.js` could include `require.js + config + app/main + app/second`. Or if you want to load `app/second` only on the second.html in production to make your main script smaller, you can have `require.js + config + app/main` in the primary bundle and optimize `app/second` into a separate bundle - the html would stay the same in both cases.

Hope this helps.